# HTML/CSS - Surrounding rectangle that is inside the div?

Tags: html, css

the UI I am implementing is made up of several "boxes" organized in several rows.

The width of a box is initially `W` (say 100px) but user can change it to be a multiple of `W`. Basically, if the first row has three boxes of width `W` and the second row has one box of width `3W` then everything aligns perfectly (i.e., the right hand side of the first row is just above the right hand side of the second row).

I am now implementing a click-to-select behavior: when the user clicks on a certain box I want/need to give a visual indication that this box is the "currently selected" one. This indication should be a rectangle that is surrounding the box with some distinct color, style.

I tried to implement this using `border: 5px; border-color: black; border-style: solid;` but this makes the rectangle appear outside of the box thus pushing its neighbors 5px in each direction, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/4z8LN/1/

Specifically, in that example, due the black frame we have (a) a vertical gap between the two rows; and (b) the right hand side of C_1_0 (light green) is not aligned with the right hand side of C_0_2 (light blue).

Is there a CSS/HTML trickery to make the border appear *inside* the div's area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on to `codehorse`'s example, if you didn't want that overlapping effect on the box-shadow you could also use an inset, like so:

```
.class {
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px black;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px black;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/w6uJp/

Then to get rid of the text coliding with the inset, add some padding:

```
.class p {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

[Example of no inset:](http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/w6uJp/2/)

[Example of inset (and with text)](http://jsfiddle.net/XeroElixir/w6uJp/3/)

Comment: @codehorse The padding was applied to the "p" element with in it, see this as an explanation:

http://jsfiddle.net/xa64Z/

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-shadow` instead of `border`. Box-shadow does not increase the width and/or height of your div like border does.

like

```
.class {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an inset box shadow for your `div .selected` as:
`box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px black inset;`

http://jsfiddle.net/BRwG3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `box-shadow`  http://jsfiddle.net/4z8LN/3/show/

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=135, Color=#000)";/*IE 8*/
-moz-box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 0px #000, inset -5px -5px 0px #000;/*FF 3.5+*/
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 0px #000, inset -5px -5px 0px #000;/*Saf3-4, Chrome, iOS 4.0.2-4.2, Android 2.3+*/
box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 0px #000, inset -5px -5px 0px #000;/* FF3.5+, Opera 9+, Saf1+, Chrome, IE10 */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=0, Direction=135, Color=#000); /*IE 5.5-7*/
```